# picamera's analog/digital gain adjustment for fixed object

Tags: camera

Could anyone please let me know if the picamera adjust its analog gain and digital gain differently at each time for fixed and stable object? The picamera documentation says that if you want to consistent image, then you need to turn the exposure_mode off. But I wonder if there is any difference between turning it on/off for fixed scene. In other words if the picamera adjustment is inconsistent for fixed scene.

I made a small experiment with the following code and found that there is no difference between turning it on and off. The analog gain and digital gain never changed. Would it be coincidence?

`with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
           camera.resolution = (2592, 1936)
           camera.framerate = 1
           camera.shutter_speed = 1000000
           camera.iso=100
           time.sleep(10)
           print("ISO: %d" %camera.iso)
           print ("Analog Gain: %02d" %camera.analog_gain)
           print ("Digital Gain: %02d" %camera.digital_gain)
           filename = 'PrintGain_%02d.jpeg' %(i)
           print (filename)
           camera.capture(filename, 'jpeg')`